# How to Code a Picture to Use it as a Display Screen?

Tags: html, css, display

I am creating a random quote machine, and thinking about using the visor on a motorcycle helmet as the display screen? Is that possible? Or is that totally impossible to achieve with code?
Here is the link to the picture that I plan to use:
[image: Motorcycle Helmet]

I would like to have the quotes from my random quote generator displayed on the glass visor of the helmet. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this image as the background of a div and then write your text inside the div.

```
<style type="text/css">
.adiv {
background-image: url('../images/aimage.png');
 }
</style>



 <div class="adiv">
div with background
</div>
```

Comment: No way it could be this easy! LOL Now I want the text to be only within the glass portion of the helmet, and I want it to remain there even if the screen size is shrunken for a mobile phone....

Comment: You will have to play with text alignment, so it end up where you want it.  Maybe have another Div inside the main div, the child div would display the quotes and should line up with the glass bit. You can do that in CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this and let you know how it works!

Comment: No problem.  Can you accept the answer if you are happy with it. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this link too https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp